# How do I compare 2 lme4 mixed models without using AIC?

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to model select manually using null hypothesis testing (for various reasons I don't want to use AIC in this case). I have used the `lme4` package to construct my models and the global model looks like this (data names changed);

```
global<- lmer(Shannon ~
                    + AN:Var1
                  + AN:Var2
                  + AN:Var3
                  + AN:Var4
                  + Var1 + Var2 + Var3
                  + Var4 + Var5 + Var6 + Var7 + (1|Random),
                  data = data, REML=FALSE)
```

I want to drop a variable out in turn and compare to the global using an `anova()` test but it throws up various errors, what am I doing wrong?

I've already found the top models using AIC, however some recent critisism of AIC which I won't go into here means that in this case I just want to strip it back. I tried a simple anova like this:

```r
anova(globalsessilebase, model1)
```

(models structured like the original post, model 1 has `var1` dropped out)
which results in this:

```
                   npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
model1              14 437.55 488.83 -204.78   409.55                     
globalsessilebase   15 438.94 493.89 -204.47   408.94 0.6101  1     0.4348
```

which is fine as far as I know, but some for some of the models (there are 11 when each variable is dropped out seqyentially) chisq is 0, which I don't really understand.

I also just tried drop1 and that just gives me the AIC values?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow!  Unfortunately we can't help without more detailed information, specifically (1) what are the "various errors" you're getting? (2) is there any chance we can have a [mre] ?

Comment: PS have you tried `drop1()` ?

Comment: just edited the post, hope it's a little clearer? Thanks for the help:)

Comment: you are probably getting 0 Chisq values because you are comparing models that are actually equivalent.   Will answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this doesn't have anything to do with mixed models, but is a consequence of the way that interactions with categorical variables work. If you have a categorical variable `f` and a numeric variable `x`, and a model that contains both the interaction `f:x` and the main effect `x`, then dropping `x` from the model doesn't actually do anything (it's not **impossible** to have an interaction without the corresponding main effect, but it violates the "principle of marginality" and R makes it difficult to do). Here's an example with `lm()` ...

```r
dd <- data.frame(z=rnorm(20),f=factor(sample(1:3,size=20,replace=TRUE)),x=rnorm(20))
m1 <- lm(z~f:x + x,dd)
m0 <- update(m1, . ~ . - x)
anova(m0,m1)
```

Results:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: z ~ f:x
Model 2: z ~ f:x + x
  Res.Df    RSS Df   Sum of Sq F Pr(>F)
1     16 11.591                        
2     16 11.591  0 -1.7764e-15
```

You can see that the residual degrees of freedom (`Res.Df`) and residual sums of squares (`RSS`) are identical, the difference in degrees of freedom is 0, and the sum-of-squares difference is essentially 0 (not exactly because of numeric inaccuracy); the p-value is missing.  The format from `anova()` for lme4 output will be slightly different, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Looks like a bit of an oversight on my part then! I feel silly for not spotting that, but at least it looks like something that will be easy to deal with. Really great explaination too :)

Comment: By the way, what are the criticisms of AIC that you're referring to? There are certainly valid criticisms of AIC but I'm not sure that replacing them with pairwise null-hypothesis tests will help much ... ?

Comment: To be honest it's all a little bit over my head, I'm an MRes student in biosciences and my supervisor suggested doing this off the back of a paper by Cade 2015 which there hasn't been an academic response to yet.
I think he was concerned because the main critisism was that the weights given relate to the model and not the parameters within it, so on the basis of that it's odd to then discuss the relative importance of the parameters within the models? Also that standardisation is only really viable on very simple models... there's definitely more to it than that but I can't recall all of it!

Comment: I sympathize. However, if all you're doing is **selecting** a model then the arguments about (1) AIC-weighted parameter averages; (2) using AIC weights for inference about variable importance shouldn't be relevant?

Comment: yeah I see your point, I'm not entirely sure what the response to that would be but I will bring it up next time we speak